# List of equations including the ones inside eqnarray

Tags: equations, lists

I am able to write my list of equations with the following commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\listofmyequations

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:GeocentricLatitude}
\varphi^{\prime} = \arctan \left[ \left( 1 - e^2 \right) \tan \left(\varphi \right) \right]
\end{equation}
\myequations{Geocentric latitude}

\begin{eqnarray}
e^2 = 1- \left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^2 = 0.006694379 \label{eq:FirstEccentricitySquared}\\
e^{\prime 2} = \dfrac{a^2}{b^2} -1 = 0.00673949674 \label{eq:SecondEccentricitySquared}
\end{eqnarray}
\myequations{First Eccentricity Squared}

\end{document}
```

The problem comes within the `eqnarray` environment, because I don't know how to refer to the two equations inside in order to list them with `myequations{}`.

Thank you

Comment: Off-topic: `eqnarray` is basically deprecated! Use `align` or `alignat` instead

Comment: I was actually using `alignat`, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: That's what I said `off-topic`. It has nothing to with your labelling problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

For this you need slightly to change your code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[2]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\ref{#2}}#1}\par}

\listofmyequations

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:GeocentricLatitude}
\varphi^{\prime} = \arctan \left[ \left( 1 - e^2 \right) \tan \left(\varphi \right) \right]
\end{equation}
\myequations{Geocentric latitude}{eq:GeocentricLatitude}

\begin{align}
e^2 
    & = 1- \left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^2 = 0.006694379
                        \label{eq:FirstEccentricitySquared}\\
e^{\prime 2} 
    & = \dfrac{a^2}{b^2} -1 = 0.00673949674 
                        \label{eq:SecondEccentricitySquared}
\end{align}
\myequations{First Eccentricity Squared}{eq:FirstEccentricitySquared}
\myequations{Second Eccentricity Squared}{eq:SecondEccentricitySquared}

\end{document}
```

As you see, I redefined your macro `\myequations`. Instead of `\theequations` I use `\ref{#2}`. Consequently, macro now have two options.

Of course, this is rude solution, so there is place to find more elegant solution. For example, use equations names for labels, etc.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly, thank you so much!